# SSIS metadata driven - doing research

Tags: ssis

Can anyone chime in with experiences building packages using metadata, i am investigating the use of such frameworks for working with a large offshore team. Some of the approaches i have seen either require heavy use of script components or stored procedures which i think somewhat defeat the purpose of using SSIS. Has anyone used Marco Russo's BIML framework?

Does anyone have experience of building on Microsoft's Metadatadriven ETL framework? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345167.aspx .

How useful is it? The packages you can create look pretty simple although they do , I presume all the columns you create in this step are exposed in the pipeline in this step (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136020.aspx) so you can add business logic?

Does microsoft provide executables for the framework, so you can use it an an out of the box (off the shelf) way? Separately, if you want to extend the framework does Microsoft  provides executables  together with source code so you can modify what they did on the   build level rather than having to build  your own by cobbling together the code snippets provided on MSDN?

Answer (score 1):

I take a hybrid approach to metadata-driven SSIS Frameworks. I build small, unit-of-work-sized "Child" packages to perform the actual data integration or ETL work. I try to limit the package to one Data Flow per package, but make necessary exceptions for loading coupled data (snowflake Kimball dimensions, for example).

I group these small packages into "SSIS Applications" and execute them serially from a "Parent" SSIS package. SSIS Application and Package metadata is stored in a database. I wrote a brief blog post about my approach and included functional (albeit simple) example code [here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/andy_leonard/archive/2011/09/16/designing-an-ssis-framework.aspx) (http://sqlblog.com/blogs/andy_leonard/archive/2011/09/16/designing-an-ssis-framework.aspx).

SSIS Frameworks can be complex. Enterprise data integration requirements drive the complexity. It could very well be you need the features afforded only by a .Net-based metadata-driven SSIS framework. It could be the hybrid approach I describe here may suffice. I advise you to learn as much as possible about SSIS before deciding.

Andy